# How can i use this sql query to hibernate criteria function

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

How can i use this sql query to hibernate criteria `select * from DailyExpense where month(tdate)=07 and year(tdate)=2016` Daily expense is my pojo class and tdate is column name. i want to select current month data only how to select based on month only.

Comment: why not use `createNativeQuery` rather than `criteria`

Comment: if i use createNativeQuery mens how to assign that list to my pojo. it was showing parsing error

Answer (score 0):

Use HQL.

```
from DailyExpense where year(birthDate)=:year and month(birthDate)=:month"
```

Afterwards, bind :year and :month parameters using query's setString(whetever value of your month and year)

Comment: SQLQuery qry=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("from DailyExpense where month(tdate)=07 and year(tdate)=2016");List<DailyExpense>dailyEx=qry.list();
  for (DailyExpense dle:dailyEx){
   System.out.println("da da da---"+dle.getExpenseId()+"---"+dle.getAmount()+"  date: "+dle.getTdate()+"  name:"+dle.getRoomMember().getMemberName());
  }    it was shoes the following error         HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query

Comment: SQLQuery qry=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("select *from DailyExpense where month(tdate)=07 and year(tdate)=2016"); i use this mens i shows the error in "Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.room.model.DailyExpense"